# Pass function that takes kwargs to solve_ivp

Tags: python, numpy, ode, solver, keyword-argument

For a class, I am using `solve_ivp`  to solve a differential equation function that I customize using keyword arguments. Here is my differential equation function `integrate` and the function `sineCurrent` I pass to it to help generate the differential equation. I already know that calling `sineCurrent` within `integrate` works. My issue arises when I try to pass `integrate` and by extension `sineCurrent` to `solve_ivp`. My class requires that they all remain separate functions.

```
def integrate(time,**kwargs):
    func = kwargs['current']
    V = kwargs['voltage']

    Cm = 0.2   # membrane capacitance in nF
    R = 100     # membrane resistance in mega-ohms
    V_rest = -60    # resting membrane voltage in mV
    I = func(time,**kwargs)   # passing arguments current input function
    s = I*R
    
    dVdt = (V_rest-V+s)/(Cm*R)
    return dVdt

def sineCurrent(time,**kwargs):
    # Passing frequency and current arguments, setting defaults to f=0.5 kHz and I=2 nA
    defaultKwargs = { 'freq': float("0.5"), 'Imax': float("2"),}
    kwargs = { **defaultKwargs, **kwargs }
    freq = kwargs['freq']
    Imax = kwargs['Imax']
    # Error message if time vector not included
    if len(time) == 0:
        return "sineCurrent requires at least one input parameter, time"
    # Calculating sineCurrent
    I = Imax*np.sin(2*pi*freq*time)
    return I
```

I tried several methods to pass `integrate` to `solve_ivp`. First, I tried using the basic`solve_ivp` syntax.

```
t = np.arange(-10,100,0.1)
V_init= np.array([50])
soln = solve_ivp(integrate,t,current=sineCurrent,[t[0], t[-1]],V_init)
```

This yielded the error `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`. Next I tried using a lambda function.

```
t = np.arange(-10,100,0.1)
V_init= np.array([50])
soln = solve_ivp(integrate=lambda t,current=sineCurrent: [t[0], t[-1]],V_init)
```

This led to the same error message as before. So I moved the keyword arguments to the end.

```
t = np.arange(-10,100,0.1)
V_init= np.array([50])
soln = solve_ivp(integrate,[t[0], t[-1]],V_init,args=(t,current=sineCurrent,voltage=V_init))
```

This led to the error message `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I am at a loss as to what to try next. I know that my `integrate` function can produce an `np.ndarray` when arguments are passed to it properly, shown below, but I cannot figure out how to pass `integrate` to `solve_ivp`.

```
dVdt = integrate(t,current=sineCurrent,voltage=V_init)
```

[image: plot of dVdt vs t]

Comment: You need to write a cover function for `integrate` that takes just positional arguments (which can be passed via `args`).  It can then pass those on to `integrate` as kwargs.  `solve_ivp` docs should be clear as to what it expects, or rather what it does.  You have to conform to its behavior - if you want things to work.

Comment: thank you! maybe i will just change the inputs for integrate to be positional arguments, although i like keyword arguments more